# kafka, confluent - 'broker' exited with 137 exit code when running with docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I'm trying to use confluent for the first time and after less than a minute the 'broker' process exits with code 137.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Docker memory is 2GB.
Confluent needs at least 8 GB to operate properly.

Change this in the Docker settings.

[Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/cp-demo/docs/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting). See docker - section 2

Comment: You could also remove services you don't need to save memory requirements

Comment: Sure, But you still need to give it 8 GB of memory.

Comment: You don't if you remove Control Center and KSQL containers. You can start Kafka in KRaft mode with less than 2GB given to Docker

Comment: But we are talking about confluent.

Comment: So? Confluent wraps Apache Kafka.